# "Unit" Testing Database

Tags: database, oracle, testing, database-schema

I'm running Oracle 11g SE1 .

Just wondering if there're any tools that would allow me to test the data integrity of a ( mostly read-only ) schema. Essentially, what I want to do is to have some queries that run every night or so and see if they return the expected result. For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PATIENTS WHERE DISEASE = 'Clone-Killing Nanovirus'; 
Expected result : 59.
```

How do people normally do such testing ?

Comment: I've heard of http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/ being used.

Comment: I'd more concerned with why someone was messing about with readonly data. Sort that out and this could be part of the "I need to mess about operation"

Comment: @TonyHopkinson we occasionally update data ( we issue update queries )... but most of the data remains the same

Comment: Two of the people who flagged this as Off Topic suggested it belong on DBA.SE.  I don't think that's right, as this is a programming question, albeit a database programming one.

Comment: Why do you need to check nightly then? Not sure you need unit testing either. A simple scheduled sql script, that emails when something is out of whack would do it. My Big concern would be maintaining it, but if change doesn't happen too often, shouldn't be that onerous. I still think it should be part of the update process though and not a scheduled occurrence

Comment: DBA = database *administration* not necessarily programming/testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could batch up your queries and run a simple perl script using DBI that would run the queries and check them against an accepted tolerance and email you if something didn't meet thresholds. I know I have written such db checking code before to make sure items were within thresholds.  Perl is a good tool for this sort of thing as the DBI module can connect to your database and then you can run some canned queries and easily send yourself an email using the MIME package.  http://www.perl.com/pub/1999/10/DBI.html

Answer (score 1):

I've used [SQLUnit](http://sqlunit.sourceforge.net/) and written about it [here](http://www.oraclenerd.com/2009/06/sqlunit-database-unit-testing.html). I don't believe any new development is being done on it but it should accomplish your goal.

[SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) (free, as in beer) also has a [Unit Testing](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E39885_01/appdev.40/e38414/unit_testing.htm#BCGHEHFE) framework. I have installed it and that's about it. I want to use it more, but I've been working with BI the past few years so no external pressure to learn it.

The tests that you want to create sound pretty simple, so either of those should work well for you. The next step would be to have them run on a schedule (cron, windows scheduler, etc) or you can go crazy with a continuous integration tool like Atlassian's [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo) (haven't used it).

Of course you could skip the tools altogether and just write up scripts that are called from the command line. Fancy would have you writing the results to a database table so you can easily skin it, simple would be piping the results to a text file and reviewing that each day.

Hope this helps.